# 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'

Tags: python, linux, django, macos, celery

I get the error "'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'"../
Here is the django settings.py

```
# celery settings
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

And, this is the celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', proj.settings)

app = Celery('proj', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

I installed rabbitmq on ubuntu linux with

```
$>sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

But, this codes work very well in mac OSX!! 
Not work on linux-ubuntu..
Do I have to install "elang"??
I think I didn't mistake at 'settings.py' and 'celery.py'.
I never know that what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that what was my mistake: I had to write these code to `__init__.py` in my project folder.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```